# Preprocessing class returns pandas dataset

Tags: python, pandas, class, oop

I'm learning how to utilise OOP in data science.

For excercise I am making preprocessing class, but I can't figure out how to return pandas dataframe

The code

```
class preprocessing:
   def __init__ (self, data_name):
    self.df = pd.read_pickle('{}.pkl'.format(data_name))
    self.df = self.df[2:].reset_index(drop=True)  
    self.df = self.df.fillna(method='ffill')
    self.df = self.df.fillna(method='bfill')


df = preprocessing('Data 11.08.2022')
```

Answer (score 1):

2 ways proposed to do it. You must tell the function to return your value, such as `return df` at the end. One creating a function in the class `get_data()` using the init method `__init__` . In this case, you pass the path to the file via `__init__`. If you want to load another file, you will need to create a new class object again.

```
class Preprocessing:
    def __init__(self, data_name):
        self.data_name = data_name

    def get_data(self):
        df = pd.read_pickle('{}.pkl'.format(self.data_name))
        df = df[2:].reset_index(drop=True).fillna(method='ffill').fillna(method='bfill')
        return df


df1 = Preprocessing('Data 11.08.2022').get_data()
df2 = Preprocessing('Data 12.08.2022').get_data()
```

Or directly without init function.

```
class Preprocessing:

    def get_data(self, data_name):
        df = pd.read_pickle('{}.pkl'.format(data_name))
        df = df[2:].reset_index(drop=True).fillna(method='ffill').fillna(method='bfill')
        return df


prep = Preprocessing()
df1 = prep.get_data('Data 11.08.2022')
df2 = prep.get_data('Data 12.08.2022')
```

Comment: Could you please explain what is the difference between the two?